# Cocoa: wait between instantiating classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, loops

I am a newbie and am having problems with creating class instances.

Here is the setup.  I have one class that loops through an array. (i will call this the "outer class" as my terminology is not up to speed yet!). On each loop, it creates an instance of another class. (which I will call the "inner class")

currently, my array has three items, and therefore three instances of the inner class are created. Because the loop on the outer class is run with lightening speed, all three inner classes are created almost simultaneously.

However, the inner class has an alert view which the user must see. Once the alert view is dismissed, the class terminates. The user response to the alert view will never stop the other inner classes from being created, but the other inner classes must not be created until the alert view is seen and dismissed.

How can I prevent the loop in the outer class from creating further inner classes until the previous inner class has terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using a loop for this; loops run at the speed of the processor; as fast as it can run the code, its executed. Since you need user interaction here, you should use some sort of callback. Create your first inner class, and set a counter (or an instance variable that's an array). In the alert callback (use the UIAlertView's delegate property), go back to your class creation code, create the second, and again stop until the alert is viewed.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I kinda understand. I can set a flag from within the inner class to say the class is finished with. However, without the loop, how will the class creation code know when to create another instance, or even if it needs to create one at all. The inner class has no idea how many times it should be used.

Comment: Use instance variables instead of local, that way you can track them through multiple calls to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect the answer will be also literally described? It will be easier for you to paste the code instead of describing it. Just a positive criticism. :)